# What is causing git byte order error?

Tags: windows-7, git, perl, msysgit

I can no longer git svn rebase (using msysgit on Windows 7).

The error starts with:

> Byte order is not compatible at ../../lib/Storable.pm

And ends with:

> Could not unmemoize function 'lookup_svn_merge', because it was not memoized to begin with

It may be overkill, but I've tried reinstalling the fule Git Extensions package with msysgit. I also made sure that cygwin git and/or perl aren't interfering. I seem to be stuck rebasing consistently on this one commit; before this, it was fine. A colleague who uses git-svn on Windows against the same subversion repository had no problems, so it's something specific to my development machine.

Comment: There's a similar Perl cache related bug [recently submitted to git-svn](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618875), which they patched.  Perhaps Google hasn't applied the same fix to msysgit (yet?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no explanation for why this worked, but deleting `.git/svn/.caches/` fixed the problem. I guess the error message was referring to the `lookup_svn_merge.db` that's stored in that folder?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of an incompatibility in data files created by Perl's `Memoize::Storable` across different versions of Perl.

It is safe to remove `.git/svn/.caches` to fix the problem.

More information can be found about the bug in [Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618875) and the discussion of the [fix](http://lists.debian.org/debian-perl/2011/05/msg00023.html).